# Find 2 Business Days

Tags: sql-server-2008, t-sql

I have a Calendar table. I would like get 2 business before Today's Date while skipping Holidays and weekeends.

For example:

Example 1: New years 2013 falls on a Tuesday. If it was Thursday (1/3), then my starting date would be Monday (12/31).

Example 2: If it was Monday (12/31), then my starting date would be Thursday (12/27).

My Clandar table as been prepopulated with 30 years worth of dates and have flags to determine which ones are weekend and hollidays. The table has these fields:

dt: Date and time for 30 years
Y: year
D: Day
M: Month
Isholiday: (Is a holiday are not, flagged with 0 for "no"  and 1 for "Yes")
IsWeekday: (Is a weekday? Flagged with 0 for "no"  and 1 for "Yes"
HolidayDescritption: Holiday Names

Please help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is what you want :

```
select top 1 *
  from ( select * 
           from Calendar 
          where IsHoliday = 0 
            and IsWeekday = 1 
            and dt between DateAdd( Day, -6, GetDate ) and GetDate() 
       ) tmpCalendar
 where dt <= DateAdd( Day, -2, GetDate() )
 order by dt desc
```

Make sure to replace `*` with only the fields that you want.

Comment: If it Is Monday (12/31), the start date should be Thursday 12/27, but the above solution gives me Friday 12/28, which is wrong. Friday is only one business day before Monday, not 2. Thanks

Comment: @Dominic this solution will return the _first_ working day that is _at least_ 2 days before today, but not always the second from today.

Answer (score 1):

Try this one:

```
SELECT dt FROM
(
    SELECT dt, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY dt DESC) AS R
    FROM
        Calendar
    WHERE
        IsHoliday = 0
        AND IsWeekday = 1
        AND dt < GETDATE()
) T
WHERE R = 2
```